# How to do socket.io implementation in Webrtc Video calling and what i have to change in the server.js?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

How to do socket.io implementation in Webrtc Video calling?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit overload but it works: [SocialVidRTC](https://github.com/tomasbasham/SocialVidRTC)

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you already have a WebRTC project and some signalling mechanism in server.js ,  possibly websockets .

To replace this with socket.io or any other signalling as SIP / XHR / AJAX etc  , you need to replace server.js with new socket.io based code for request and response .

Follow these steps :

1. create a https server ( since webrtc pages capture web cam input only from secure origins) for socket.io. Assign server to an variable say **app**.

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var https = require('https');

   var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('ssl_certs/server.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl_certs/server.crt'),
     ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl_certs/ca.crt'),
     requestCert: true,
     rejectUnauthorized: false
   };

   var app = https.createServer(options, function(request, response){
           request.addListener('end', function () {
           file.serve(request, response);
       }).resume();     
   });

   app.listen(8081);
   ```

here server.key , server.crt and ca.crt are fake ssl certs and 8081 is the https port I have selected .
you can reuse the same https server for hosting the webpages also.

2. listen on this same port for socket.io using **app** defined earlier

   ```
   var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, {
       log: false,
       origins: '*:*'
   });

   io.set('transports', [
       'websocket'
   ]);
   ```

I choose only websocket but you can set other types of transport too such as

```
socket.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

3. Now implement signalling specific functions and calls such as ,

   ```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
       ...
           socket.on('webrtc-joinchannel',function(data){
               var resp=joinChannel(data);
          socket.emit('resp-webrtc-joinchannel', resp);
           });
   ...
   });
   ```

**Note : I am using socket.io v0.9 .**

If yo want a example implementation you can view any sample projects such as [here](https://github.com/altanai/webrtc)